# How to get admins to actually use SCOM?

Tags: scom

We implemented [SCOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Center_Operations_Manager) in our internal infrastructure. However, I have the impression that is isn't used as it could be.

For example: we have had regular incidents in our production (and other) environments that could have been prevented by monitoring SCOM. An example: servers that fail to operate because of a full disk. This could have been signaled by SCOM, and prevented by clearing a buffer.

When an incident is logged by our users, the admins do not use SCOM to diagnose a problem, they will ask the developers directly to help them. When asked to look at SCOM, then they will open the management application, but it isn't active. SCOM isn't monitored on a regular basis for preventive maintenance.

I don't think this is a technical problem (SCOM is implemented, and could by finetuned, when actually used). Also i don't think it is a matter of SCOM vs an other preferred tool. I think this is a 'social' problem, as the admins just don't use the tooling that is present.

I'm asking this question here, since i expect users here may have experience is these matters.

I have no authority on the admins, i can only suggest improvements, or lobby for the importance of keeping the environment and applications running.

**How can i motivate the admins to use SCOM for preventive maintenance? How can i motivate the admins to prevent incidents and keep the applications running?**

Answer (score 4):

This is entirely policy related and there's nothing you can do except suggest it if you're not in charge. If you want an admin to do something and they don't, then discipline if the only way. If you're not in a position to discipline anyone, then it's not your decision to make.

You could always present your case to their manager and hope for the best, but beyond that, it's out of your hands.